# Steam pressure and constant fuel temperature in steam turbines

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, temperature, conservation-laws

I've heard that leaving a steam turbine unsupervised can lead to you losing your life.

The reason they state is that the heating medium (or whatever it's called) such as coal or gas, produces variable temperatures as the combustion rate can increase/decrease over the time period. Ultimately, the steam's pressure, too, is variable and not constant. And should the steam pressure exceed the vessel's rating, you are as good as dead.

My question is: If we melt a salt mixture and it reaches, say 485°C, and then use the molten salt as the heating medium (by passing it through a heat exchanger) for the steam, can I leave the turbine unsupervised, as I know that the steam will not heat up once the system reaches equilibrium and there is no external heat supply. Note that the salt will only lose heat, not gain any.

Answer (score 1):

Steam turbines get their steam from boilers.  Both boilers and steam turbines have control systems on them which implement various levels of control, from normal operation to emergency shutdown.  This means that no boiler or steam turbine is ever unsupervised.  Changing the heating medium to a molten salt does not change this fact, as a heat source would still be needed to heat the salt to provide process heat, pumps would still need to send that molten salt around a circuit of heat exchangers, and all that equipment would still need to be continuously monitored to prevent unsafe process excursions.